# What is the equivalent of Java's Main Method in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, methods, swift2

Does swift execute all functions (including custom) in the '.swift' file simultaneously? Or is there a main method in which you have to call the other ones? Because I want to call a certain method in my game, whenever the player hits the edge of the screen.

Comment: Are you making an iOS/Mac app project, or is this just a single Swift file / Playground?

Comment: You can use the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the `AppDelegate.swift`. However, you generally write code in `ViewController.swift`. There, you can use `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.